# Can't install docTR. Why?

Tags: python, module, package, google-colaboratory, ocr

I have been following the git Install guide for docTR and could successfully install it in a google colab. When I try it identically in my local PyCharm I always got error:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'doctr.io'; 'doctr' is not a package

I retrieve it with:

from doctr.io import DocumentFile
from doctr.models import ocr_predictor

I tried it in a fresh anaconda env aswell as venv, both throw the same error. I tried the tensorflow pip install aswell as the git clone. Always "ModuleNotFoundError"

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me:

```
! pip install python-doctr tf2onnx
from doctr.io import DocumentFile
from doctr.models import ocr_predictor
```

I'm using a TPU, but I've tested with just CPU as well.